# Define "Islamist"

Tags: meaning, adjectives, synonyms, word-usage, vocabulary

If you google "Islamist definition" the result you'll get is:

> an advocate or supporter of Islamic militancy or fundamentalism

Google says they receive their definitions from Oxford Languages (run by the Oxford University Press).  Yet, when I [search](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/islamist) for "islamist" in the Oxford Dictionary (also run by the Oxford University Press) I get:

> a person who believes strongly in the teachings of Islam

Additionally, the [AP Stylebook](https://www.politico.com/blogs/media/2013/04/ap-stylebook-revises-islamist-use-160943) specifically states:

> Do not use [Islamist] as a synonym for Islamic fighters, militants, extremists or radicals, who may or may not be Islamists.

These two definitions are vastly different, so I'd like some help on understanding what exactly the word "islamist" means.

Comment: Did you check any other dictionaries?  There are a half-dozen different ones that Google will find.

Comment: The Oxford definition you get in Google is the same as the one in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/islamist), NOAD, and maybe some others. Oxford has many dictionaries.

Comment: I take the AP as good advice: Do not equate all those who are both Muslim and "fighters, militants, extremists or radicals" to be Islamists by definition.

Answer (score 2):

*Islamic* means related to *Islam*. *Islamist* means related to ***Islamism***. These are two very different things: Islam is a religion while Islamism is a broad set of various related but often very different political ideologies.

The [OED gives](https://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/299210):

> ### A. *n.*
>
> 1. a. A Muslim. Now *rare.*
>    b. An Islamic fundamentalist; a supporter or advocate of increasing the influence of Islamic law in politics and society.
> 2. An expert or specialist in Islamic history, culture, etc.
>
> ### B. *adj.*
>
> 1. Of or relating to Islam or Muslims; Islamic, Muslim.
> 2. Of or relating to Islamic fundamentalism or Islamic fundamentalists; that advocates or supports increasing the influence of Islamic law in politics and society.

The *Encyclopædia Britannica* has a [very large section](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Islamism) on this. It begins:

> Islamism, also called political Islam, is a broad set of political ideologies that utilize and draw inspiration from Islamic symbols and traditions in pursuit of a sociopolitical objective. The aims and objectives of these movements vary widely, as do their interpretations of Islamic tradition and practice, and, as such, **the precise scope and definition of the term remain debated.**

> ...

> The adjective *Islamist*, denoting someone or something in pursuit of a sociopolitical objective using the symbols and traditions of Islam, is distinguished from the term *Islamic*, which refers directly to aspects of Islam as a religion.

We shall not be able to provide you with the precise definition that you seem to seek, as this is not a settled matter. This is a word that has been around for almost two centuries. As such, it has meant many things to many people over time. If you want to know what someone means by it, you must ask them.

Comment: Exactly. Usage varies, and of course, dictionaries aren't updated in real time. For historical purposes, consider how "Colored" was used in NAACP, but over time, became an offensive term. My students vary between self identifying as "Black" or "Of Color."